# Разбор UML диаграммы классов ООП

Tags: классы, uml, диаграммы

### Добрый день

Есть задача построить смоделировать UML диаграмму класса работы системы Ресторана...

Я подумал все и начал строить.. Если у нас система ресторана значит нужно писать то что имеет ресторан:

Моя диаграмма будет иметь такие классы как:

- Ресторан
- Столик
- Покупатель
- Заказ
- Оффициант
- Меню
- Еда
- Счет

Решил сделать и получилось у меня вот так
 [image: UML]

Я показал данную диаграмму учителю, но он сказал что не правильно...

Данную диаграмму я менял не раз... И все равно не правильно.. Можете подсказать что и как мне сделать?

Comment: могу лишь посоветовать `Lynda.com | Основы программирования: объектно-ориентированное проектирование (2012)` линк найдете сами)) там есть UML